# accessing var outside ui:repeat JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I want to access a variable through out my page. The var is declared inside a ui:repeat element. Heard that the scope of the variable in only inside the repeat tag. I want to load another div on the same page which need the details inside this var. How can I achieve this.

```
<ui:repeat var="errorDetails"
    value="#{adminDashboardController.errorDetails}" varStatus="status">

    <tr>
        <td>#{errorDetails.issueName}</td>
        <td>#{errorDetails.priority}</td>
        <td>#{errorDetails.comments}</td>
        <td><h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary btn-xs view-issue"
                value="View" /></td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>

<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">#{errorDetails.issueName}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `errorDetails` variable is only available in the scope of the `ui:repeat`.

You have here two options:

**HTML/JS solution**: Generate HTML code which contains one `<h4...>#{errorDetails.issueName}</h4>` for each line of your table and use JavaScript to display the right block when pressing on the command button.

I think that this option should be only used for performance reason, because you will generate lot of HTML and because as a JSF developer you usually prefer to avoid coding custom things in JavaScript.

**JSF solution** (my preferred one): use a backing bean to hold the currently viewed error detail. That would be something like this:

```
<ui:repeat var="errorDetails" value="#{adminDashboardController.errorDetails}" varStatus="status">
    ...
    <h:commandButton ... action="#{adminDashboardController.showDetails(errorDetails)" update="myModalLabel" />
    ...
</ui:repeat>

...

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminDashboardController.currentDetail != null}">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">#{adminDashboardController.currentDetail.issueName}</h4>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `AdminDashboardController.showDetails` methods would save the given error detail in a the field `currentDetail`.

Comment: Thanks Laurent for your reply. I couldn't find an update attribute in my <h:commandButton>.